# Is the force $F$ in formula of longitudinal stress applied on both sides of a rod?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, elasticity, stress-strain

Suppose a force $F$ is applied on one face of a rod (with cross-sectional area $A$) and one end is fixed.
And now suppose another situation with the same rod, force $F$ is applied on both faces of the rod (the rod is now freed from one end).
So my question is, what formula should be applied in each case to calculate longitudinal stress, should it be
**stress = F/A**
or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two situations you describe are equivalent.

When you do a free body diagram of the rod having one end fixed, you remove the fixed support and replace it with its reaction tension or compression force, $F$, as applicable. That makes it equivalent to your second case, with the rod free and equal and opposite forces at each end keeping it in equilibrium.

Bottom line: Stress= F/A for both cases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank a lot....